# How to escape whole sql query from user input for Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, escaping

I understand there are two common ways to do it: 1. escape 2. parameterized query
But I need to allow users to write the SQL queries by themselves.

For example, this is what users can write:

```
SELECT aaa, 'bbb', CONCAT('mmm', nnn) FROM XXX;
```

I can't find and escape 'bbb' and 'mmm' or parameterize it.
Is there any way to do this properly?